# How to load unity scenes asynchronously?

Tags: unity, game-design

If i am playing scene 1, i want to load the scene2 in parallel, so after the completion of scene 1 i will smoothly transition to scene 2 without loading, is there is any option for this?

Comment: Presumably you started by searching and found the documentation for LoadSceneAsync. How have you tried putting your research into practice so far?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't find right solution☹

Comment: What solutions did you find, and what made them not right for your needs? If you don't tell us that, we're likely to tell you the same solutions you already found and rejected.

Comment: As DMGregory stated, everything you need to know should be here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html

Comment: AsyncOperation ao = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
 ao.allowSceneActivation = false; if(ao.progress == 0.9f); after the completion of 1st scene, i say ao.allowSceneActivation = true; by using this method  it affects the performance of 1st scene i think!!! Or tell ur suggestion

Comment: I have another doubt , if games like limbo, inside. it contains many scenes or one scene itself all the stuffs are loaded, how they make levels without any loading??

Comment: 1) Your code belongs in your question, not in the comments. 2) "it affects the performance of 1st scene I think!!" You *think*? How have you measured this? Show us your profiling results and we can help you fix the bug. 3) "how [does Limbo] make levels without any loading?" [has been answered before](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/183775/39518) - they load and unload the off-screen sections asynchronously, like the docs describe.

Comment: Asynchronous loading can affect performance depending on the specific platform you're running on (e.g. desktop, web, phone), the hardware in that platform (CPU, RAM, storage medium), and the size and complexity of the content you're loading. Ideally it won't affect performance, but in reality it depends on a lot of things. You'll have to figure out the right solution through testing.